# Cache maven dependencies from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, maven, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Despite having configured BuildKit, I am facing an issue where dependencies continue to be downloaded during the build process. Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this unwanted behavior or suggestions on how to fix this problem?

I have a gitlab-ci.yml like this:

```yaml
.
.
.
deploy-backend:
  stage: deploy-backend
  before_script:
    - apk update && apk add aws-cli
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY
  script:
    - DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker buildx build -t test --build-arg TARGETENV=qa .
.
.
.
```

Dockefile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4
ARG MAVEN_VERSION=jelastic/maven:3.9.5-temurinjdk-21
ARG OPENJDK_VERSION=eclipse-temurin:21.0.1_12-jre-alpine

FROM $MAVEN_VERSION AS build

ARG TARGETENV=dev

WORKDIR /home/app
COPY mvnw /home/app 
COPY .mvn /home/app/.mvn

COPY [ "./pom.xml", "/home/app" ]
COPY [ "./src", "/home/app/src" ]

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 ./mvnw dependency:go-offline

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 ./mvnw package -Dquarkus.profile=${TARGETENV} -DskipTests
.
.
.
```

/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

```ini
[[runners]]
  name = "xxxx"
  url = "xxx"
  id = 46
  token = "xxx"
  token_obtained_at = 2024-01-05T13:57:44Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    Insecure = false
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>xxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>21</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>3.6.6</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.1.2</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  geometry data dependencies  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.bedatadriven</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jts</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wololo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jts2geojson</artifactId>
      <version>0.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
      <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.locationtech.jts.io</groupId>
      <artifactId>jts-io-common</artifactId>
      <version>1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  aws dependencies  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>kms</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  spring dependencies  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
      <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
      <version>2.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-liquibase</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-oidc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkiverse.hibernatetypes</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-types</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.30</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Caching maven dependencies also depend on pom.xml configuration. Can you show pom.xml file?

Comment: yes, i can, updated